# Putting a SOAP request in a here-string

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

I am trying to code a script that will send random SOAP requests for testing another process. However I can can't seem to create the variable. Everytime I copy/paste the code from Notepad to the PS console, the script ends in >> (even after hitting enter multiple times). The same thing happens even if I copy/paste just the `$SOAPRequest` part of the script. If I comment out the entire here-string, the script runs (albeit with errors due to the missing SOAP content).

I've tried various combinations of the following:

- Escaping the pound symbols with a backslash
- Deleting lines that contain pound symbols
- Creating the variable with SOAP request in Powershell v1 and Powershell v2
- Deleting all lines with http addresses
- Using @''@ (not only didn't work but I need variable expansion)

**Question**: How can I get Powershell to set the content in the here-string to the `$SOAPRequest` variable? In other words, how can I stop the >>? Usually it means I've missed a parentheses, a bracket or a double quote but I can't seem to find anything like that. I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Pages I looked for help:

- [Powershell SOAP request with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401776/powershell-soap-request-with-parameter)
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/17/use-powershell-to-simplify-working-with-xml-data.aspx

The $SOAPRequest variable:

```
$SOAPRequest = [xml] @"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soa="http://bmc.com/ao/xsd/2008/09/soa">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">#PASSWD#</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<soa:executeProcess>
<soa:gridName>GRID</soa:gridName>
<soa:processName>Software_Distribution</soa:processName>
<soa:parameters>
<soa:Input>
<soa:Parameter>
<soa:Name required="true">Software Request</soa:Name>
<soa:Value soa:type="xs:anyType">
<soa:XmlDoc>
<request>
<Source>SourceName</Source>
<Command>create</Command>
<Debug>true</Debug>
<DeployType>standard</DeployType>
<PkgId>$pkgID</PkgId>
<PackageName>$pkgName</PackageName>
<PackageShareLocation>\\Network\Share\With\Content</PackageShareLocation>
<PackageFormat>exploded</PackageFormat>
<InstallScript>install.bat</InstallScript>
<InstallTimeout>3600</InstallTimeout>
<SilentInstall>True</SilentInstall>
<Emails />
</request>
</soa:XmlDoc>
</soa:Value>
</soa:Parameter>
</soa:Input>
</soa:parameters>
</soa:executeProcess>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@
```

Even though this issue seems related specificaly to the here-string, this is the rest of the script for context:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Variables
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
$pkgID = 346
$pkgNameList = @("Package_ABC", "Package_DEF", "Package_XYZ", "Package_123" )

#Set start/end datestamps
$now= Get-Date
$end = Get-Date "04/03/2013 08:00 AM"


$testDirectory = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\AutomatedSOAPTest"
if (!(Test-Path $testDirectory)){
    New-Item $testDirectory -itemType directory | Out-Null
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#Function to write to SOAP request log
function Write-Log($message)
{
    $logDate = Get-Date -format "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"
    $logPath = "$testDirectory\progress.log"

    Write-Output "$logDate $message" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append
}#end Write-Log function

#Function to write to SOAP return log
function Write-Return($xml, $item)
{
    $logDate = Get-Date -format "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"
    $logPath = "$testDirectory\SOAP_return-$item.log"

    $success = $xml.status.success
    $message = $xml.status.message

    Write-Output "Request returned for $item on $logDate" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append
    Write-Output "Success: $success" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append
    Write-Output $message | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append
}#end Write-Log function

#Function to call SOAP request
function Execute-SOAPRequest(
    [Int]    $pkgID,
    [String] $pkgName
)
{
    $SOAPRequest = [xml] @"
        <SOAP request content here>
    "@

    $SOAPurl = "http://<site where requests are sent>"

    Write-Log "Sending SOAP Request for $pkgName To Server: $SOAPurl"
    $soapWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($SOAPurl)
    $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","`"`"")

    $soapWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=`"utf-8`""
    $soapWebRequest.Accept      = "text/xml"
    $soapWebRequest.Method      = "POST"

    Write-Log "Initiating Send."
    $requestStream = $soapWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $SOAPRequest.Save($requestStream)
    $requestStream.Close()

    Write-Log "Send Complete, Waiting For Response."
    $resp = $soapWebRequest.GetResponse()
    $responseStream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
    $soapReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]($responseStream)
    $ReturnXml = [Xml] $soapReader.ReadToEnd()
    $responseStream.Close()

    Write-Log "Response Received."

    Write-Return $ReturnXml.status.success
    Write-Return $ReturnXml.status.message
}#End Execute-SOAPRequest function

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Code
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

while($now -lt $end)
{
    $pkgList = Get-Random -input $pkgNameList -count 4

    foreach($pkgName in $pkgList)
    {
        #Run function to execute SOAP request
        Execute-SOAPRequest $pkgID $pkgName

        $pkgID++
    }

    Start-Sleep -s 3600
    $now = Get-Date
}
```

The code for the Execute-SOAPRequest function came from here: http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/execute-a-soap-request-from-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminating "@ in your here string must start in col 1.

It appears when you pasted it into the code, it was indented, and the leading spaces from the indention are causing the parser to continue to read the following code as part of the here-string.  Since the string was never properly terminated, the >> is a prompt for more data for the here-string, or the terminating "@.

Edit:  If you don't want to mess up your indentation in the Process block, you can move an expandable  here-string into the Begin block as a scriptblock, and the invoke it later:

```
Begin{
$SoapString = {
@"
This is my here-string containing $variable
"@
}
}


Process{
$variable = "MY VARIABLE"

  foreach ($x in 1)
   {
     &$SoapString
    }
}


This is my here-string containing MY VARIABLE
```

If you don't like it cluttering up the head of the script, you can put the Being block at the bottom if you want. Powershell will still run them in the order of Begin, Process, End, no matter what order they are in the script:

```
Process{
$variable = "MY VARIABLE"

  foreach ($x in 1)
   {
     &$SoapString
   }
}

Begin{
$SoapString = {
@"
This is my here-string containing $variable
"@
}
}

This is my here-string containing MY VARIABLE
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't realize the opening and closing of the here-string had to start in column 1. Thanks!

Comment: The opening doesn't have to, but the closing must.